# On executing a query in table A a column in table B must increment its value by 1 or update its value as 2

Tags: mysql, servlets

Im working on a project where i need to assign the vehicle number that is currently free  to a customer who needs a cab. So vehicle status would change from 1 to 2 upon assigning.

Now this vehicle status is in vehicledetails table.Vehicle number is getting updated in tripdetails table.

when i assign the free vehicle i'm actually updating it to tripdetails table.

Im not able to understand how to increase the tripstatus from 1 to 2 automatically in vehicledetails table upon assigning the vehicle to customer.

Please show me some directions or any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use triggers in this case. The below code might be useful for you:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.server_triggers
    WHERE name = 'trg_tbl_vehicledetails')
DROP TRIGGER trg_tbl_vehicledetails
ON ALL SERVER;
GO
CREATE TRIGGER trg_tbl_vehicledetails
ON tbl_tripdetails 
AFTER UPDATE 
AS 
    <Update query on 'tbl_vehicledetails'>
GO
```

Comment: Hi my actual table name of vehicledetails is driver_vehicle_details and tripdetails is trip_details.

I have tried to write the code as below by refering the code that you provided.Please confirm if its correct.

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.server_triggers
    WHERE name = 'trg_tbl_driver_vehicle_details')
DROP TRIGGER trg_tbl_driver_vehicle_details
ON ALL SERVER;
GO
CREATE TRIGGER trg_tbl_driver_vehicle_details
ON tbl_trip_details 
AFTER UPDATE 
AS 
    <update driver_vehicle_details set vehicle_status=2>
GO

Comment: Please remove the '<' and '>' symbols from the update query. This was just written so that you can replace it with you code.

Are you updating the whole table with vehicle_status = 2, or you want to update the record for a particular vehicle? Please check your query.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good scenario where [triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) come in handy.

Basically - when updating the customer record with the vehicle you trigger an update of the vehicledetails table.

Comment: I'm new to writing triggers ! Will try with triggers! Thank you :)